# Powershell MQ Snap-in MO74 doesn't work correctly

Tags: powershell, ibm-mq

I have downloaded and installed MO74: WebSphere MQ - Windows PowerShell Library on a Windows Server 2012 with IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer Version: 7.5.0.2
The original website is website http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24017698&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en

I have both tried to install for powershell 64bit and for powershell 32bit.

For 64bit I can add the plugin (Add-PSSnapin IBM.Powershell.WebsPhereMQ) without errors.
Afterwards the commands (for instance a simple Get-WMQQueue) gives no errors but no results as well.

For 32bit I can't even load the plugin.
The error is: 
Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'IBM.Powershell.WebsPhereMQ' is not installed on this computer.

Anyone has this working with Windows Server 2012 and have a clue what can be wrong?

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5? By default these are not installed on Windows 2012 server

Comment: I have .NET Framework v3.5 and v4.0.30319

Comment: MQ74 ships a shortcut to Powershell in it's install directory. Did you running that? You may want to drop an email to MQ74 developers describing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Installed MO74 on Windows Server 2012. System already had MQ8.0 installed on it. The Get-WMQQueue cmdlet works for me.

Got to know from the MO74 developers that MO74 can be used with 32 bit PowerShell only. Support for 64 bit PowerShell is not available yet.